# Azure Data Factory Lookup Activity Query Error The Operation Has Timed Out

Tags: oracle, azure, optimization, azure-data-factory

I'm using **ORACLE DB** and I have a select statement that has multiple joins. I have a Lookup Activity that has no issue executing a normal select statement. Connections are working fine to ORACLE DB.

Here is the query inside the Lookup.

```
SELECT

  A.KEY as "keyValue"

,A.QUEUE

,A.WORK_CREATED_DATE

FROM (SELECT

        main.KEY_DATE || '-' || main.KEY_TIME || '.' || main.KEY_MILSEC || main.RECORDCD || main.CRNODE  AS "KEY"

       ,trim(main.QUEUECD)    AS "QUEUE"

       ,main.KEY_DATE         AS "WORK_CREATED_DATE"   

      FROM BI.WA4U999S main

      INNER JOIN AWD.AWDBE meta ON

                to_timestamp((main.KEY_DATE || main.KEY_TIME|| main.KEY_MILSEC),'YYYY-MM-DDHH24:MI:SSFF8') = meta.CRDATTIM

            AND main.RECORDCD = meta.RECORDCD

            AND main.CRNODE = meta.CRNODE

      ) A
```

I'm testing this query in ADF through **PREVIEW DATA** and by checking sometimes the **FIRST ROW ONLY** in the dataset.

I still have a lot of tables needed to JOIN in this query and whenever I add this JOIN statement in the Query.

```
  INNER JOIN AWD.W06U999S mainUser ON
            trim(meta.USER_001) = trim(mainUser.USERID)
```

The Preview Data option is failing and returning an ***Error Code 11408 The Operation Has Timed Out***. I've **removed** also the **TRIM** function but it still doesn't work.

Running the Pipeline via Debug Operation is not an option since the Lookup Activity will just run for more than an hour then returns the same error.

I'm not sure what's causing the issue or maybe there's a better way to handle this JOIN statement between multiple tables in ADF.

Comment: I have done Lookups to Oracle with a couple dozen joins before, much more complex than this and it's worked fine.... You have been able to run just a simple LOOKUP in ADF against the Oracle DB?

Comment: Are you using the AutoResolveIntegrationRuntime or a Self Hosted Integration Runtime? Is your Oracle Database behind a virtual network/firewall?

Comment: We are using SELF HOSTED. It's in our clients server. For FIREWALL restrictions not sure since we are connecting to this server a long time now.

Comment: How long does it take to get the first row when running this query directly on Oracle, not using ADF? Also, do you have any say in what indexes are on these tables?

Comment: ADF is just an orchestrator . Before trying that query via ADF, would request you to try the  same query directly on database and check out the time it takes to return the result

Comment: I can't specify the exact time because of limit of caching rows only limits to 200. But based on the number of records which is 370,271 so I think the query will run for a while.

Comment: If you took your exact query and added "WHERE ROWNUM <= 10" how long does it take to get all 10 records when querying against Oracle directly? If it takes just a few seconds or even a minute, I would expect data preview to work, if it takes 20 minutes, I wouldn't be surprised to see data preview fail with a timeout. Without more information it's very difficult, but I may answer this question with the assumption your query is solid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, a Lookup Activity limits max query results to 5,000 rows, so you are definitely breaking that limit. Usually people use a Lookup so that they can iterate over every row or object returned in the array.

But,
Assuming your query is running fine against Oracle directly and there are no Query issues. These items should help you resolve your issue, or at the very least troubleshoot your issue (keep in mind, 300k rows will still result in a lookup error, so if you reduce your row volume to < 5k you should get results back):

[image: Oracle Lookup Example]

Cheers!

Comment: The main purpose for that query is for those 300K rows to be inserted into a MSSQL Table using COPY DATA activity. I've tried running it and waited for 2 hours before it crashes. Do I just need only to adjust the Query Timeout (minutes) to something longer?

Comment: Yes, the default is 2 hours, if you hit 2 hours it will automatically fail with timeout. Though.... I would expect that on your output details though, that you would have some records read from source within that two hours. Even if something fails you still have an output details that shows throughput, rows read, rows written, etc